# Excel TEXT() Formula Getting the Month returning "mmm"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got a report in excel and I'm having some trouble with a Russian PC. The formula TEXT is being used to get the month name from a date but, in the Russian PC it's not working and not given an error.

The formula is `=TEXT(D7, "mmm")` and the result is `"mmm"`.

I also tried (The excel way to handle dates in different languages):

`=TEXT(D7, "[$-409]mmm")` and the result is `"mmm"`.

I've tested different date functions and they all working. (`Sum()`, `month()`, changing data format, etc).

Version: `Excel 365`

As it works in my pc, does anyone have any idea what might be causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

First - The `mmm` should be `MMM`.

Then, the fact that the PC is in Russian is a bit irrelevant. What matters is the installation language of Excel.

You may try the following

- write `43319` on range `A1`;
- then write this formula `=TEXT(A1,"MMM")`, using the English `M` and not the Cyrillic ones. Although they look quite the same, they are different.
- it should return `Aug` as the month;

Comment: If I copy `ММ` directly out of the RU-RU docs and test the character code, I come up with ascii 63 (unicode 1052). Not what I would expect from an EN-US M (ascii 77).

Comment: @Jeeped - if you copy any of these words - `=ТЕКСТ(СЕГОДНЯ();"ДД.ММ.ГГ")` you would get 63. Guess you are using something like this - `?Asc(Range("A1"))`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838639/character-looks-like-ascii-63-but-isnt-so-i-cant-remove-it

Comment: No, just CODE(...) and UNICODE(...) on the worksheet.

Comment: @Jeeped - yeah, the built-in formulas are faster.

Comment: Sorry, for taking too long to answer. But it didn't work as well. I've tried to use the number format stead date, but the result is always the same "MMM".

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to fix it creating a new formula in VBA and it worked great.

Press Alt+F11 (to open the VBA editor) Then Click the menu item Insert > Module In the new VBA module, enter the following:

```
Public Function FMT$(ByVal Value, ByVal strFormat)
    FMT = VBA.Format$(Value, strFormat)
End Function
```

To use this, simply type `=FMT(A1, "MMM")` instead of `=TEXT(A1, "MMM")`.

Credits to https://superuser.com/questions/730371/how-to-prevent-excel-to-use-the-os-regional-settings-for-date-patterns-in-formul