# Pasting after using DataObject.PutInClipboard returns unknown characters

Tags: vba, clipboard

I am using the following code to copy text to the clipboard for the user to paste afterwards:

```
Sub CopyText(ByVal StringToCopy As String)
    Dim D As DataObject
    Set D = New DataObject
    With D
       .SetText StringToCopy 
       .PutInClipboard
    End With
    Set D = Nothing
End Sub
```

It worked fine for a long time on multiple machines. It stopped working in the past few month. Instead of returning copied text it returns two unknown characters that show up as `??` in the immediate pane or character 63 if I run `?Asc(.GetText)` which according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25838700/8597922) means text is not recognized.
The string is lost after `.PutInClipboard`:

```
.SetText "Test"
Debug.Print .GetText `returns "Test"
.PutInClipboard
Debug.Print .GetText `returns "??"
```

The only [solution I have found so far](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/48e8c30c-24ee-458e-a873-a4e6e13f5926/dataobject-settext-and-putinclipboard-sequence-puts-invalid-data-hex-63-characters-in-clipboard?forum=isvvba) suggests using API calls, which I would like not to do if possible.

Edit: after following up on the thread from msdn is appears that the issue is reproduced if the File Explorer is open.

Comment: [The second answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/48e8c30c-24ee-458e-a873-a4e6e13f5926/dataobject-settext-and-putinclipboard-sequence-puts-invalid-data-hex-63-characters-in-clipboard) is the only thing I have found to work. It's fairly trivial though, only detriment is that it takes up text in your module.

Comment: @jclasley after looking further in the discussion in the linked thread it appears that the issue only shows up if file explorer is open.